# 3D surface plot in R for Beta and Dirichlet distributions (A Bayesian model for rock,paper,scissors)

Tags: r, 3d

What I am trying to do is create a 3d surface plot for my data. I have created a Bayesian multinomial model for the rock paper scissors game; a prior distribution theta (a vector with three marginals; theta1, theta2, theta3) which follows the Dirichlet distribution, a sampling model which consists of 1000 draws from the multinomial distribution, and then based on this output I updated my parameters in the posterior distribution (which still follows the Dirichlet distribution). Below I am looking to do a 3d surface plot of the marginals theta1, theta2, theta3 which follow the Beta(10,20) distribution in this case.

What I want is for rock1 to be on the x axis, paper1 to be on the y axis and scissors1 to be the z axis. I understand that I need the length of z = length of x * length of y, since I have matrices for x and y stated below, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Can anyone please help with the following?

```
>x=theta1=rbeta(1000,10,20)
>y=theta2=rbeta(1000,10,20)
>z=1-x-y
>surface3d(x,y,z)
```

Comment: You forgot to add "lizard Spock"  :-) .   But to help out:  take a look at the `plot3D` package, and its function `mesh` which creates the `x,y,z` matrices . There are examples under `?surf3D`  and other plotting functions in that package.

Comment: haha, maybe I'll include Lizard and Spock in my advanced model! Thanks,  will have another look at those.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you what you ask for, but speaking with my statistical art critic hat on, it doesn't seem very interesting.

```
x=theta1=rbeta(100,10,20)
y=theta2=rbeta(100,10,20)
z=outer(x,y,FUN=function(x,y){1-x-y}); require(rgl); open3d()
surface3d(x,y,z); decorate3d(xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z")
```

[image]

I also question whether it really represents the underlying Dirichlet model.

I get this from a Latex previewer for the code below in the comments:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for that reply! Appreciate it. Yes I agree, it doesn't look particularly interesting. What I'm trying to do is get 3d surface plots for the prior and posterior (both following Dirichlet distribution) for a few cases so I can look at the effect of varying the initial alpha parameters in the prior. The reason I initially thought of using the beta distribution here is because the marginals of theta (with theta following the Dirchlet distribution) follow the beta distribution. The form of the posterior in this multinomial model can be written proportionally as..

Comment: $p\left(\theta|y\right) \propto \prod_{j=1}^3 \theta_j^{\alpha_j + y_j - 1}
\propto \textit{Dir}\left(\theta|\alpha_1 + y_1, \alpha_2 + y_2, \alpha_3 + y_3 \right)$. But looking at the code I have above I now see that this is not going to actually represent the underlying Dirichlet model like you say. Do you think the way to go about this would be to plot a 3d surface where x, y, z are all draws from the relevant Dirichlet distribution?

Comment: The draws from a Dirichlet-3 distribution are going to be triples that sum to 1. (I don't read native LateX.) There are packages with `rdirichlet`